# canvas object update position and redraw the object

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas with two rectangle objects drawn on initialising the page.

I have a variable for X and Y that changes when a keyboard button is pressed which works ok.

I wanted to move one of the object squares "playerCar" by the new X and Y values as they change, but I cannot get the box to change.

I got it working with out using an object but would like to use objects so I can add more (when I learn it).

I have tried `playercar.draw(keyX, KeyY);`  but this is not updating.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('plot');
var context;

var keyX = 100;
var keyY = 100;

playerCar = new car(100, 100, 'red');
playerCar2 = new car(350, 100, 'blue');

init()
playerCar.draw();
playerCar2.draw();


document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  var keyPressed = event.keyCode;
  switch(keyPressed){
    case 104:
      keyY = keyY -1;
      break;
    case 98:
      keyY = keyY +1;
      break;
    case 100:
      keyX = keyX -1;
      break;
    case 102:
      keyX = keyX +1;
      break;
  }
  
  playerCar.draw();

  console.log('key Y = ' + keyY);
  console.log('key X = ' + keyX);
});

function init(){
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.fillStyle = "green";
  var plot = {height: 800, width: 800};
  context.fillRect(1, 1, plot.width, plot.height);
}

function car (keyX, keyY, color){
  carwidth = 150;
  carHeight = 100;
  this.x = keyX;
  this.y = keyY;
  this.color = color;
  this.draw = function (){
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, carwidth, carHeight);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <canvas id="plot" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is you're counting on the initial values of KeyX and KeyY and not those stored within the car object.
You need to increment on `playerCar.y`

So I replaced `keyY = keyY +1;` to `playerCar.y += 1;`.
As you can see I used += which is just a shorter way of writing the same thing,
see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators

You could also use `playerCar.y++` but then you can't tweak the amount it's adding anymore.

Aside from that problem you also got a problem that you're not redrawing your canvas. This is a slightly bigger problem and in most games you would have a draw function(loop) that takes care of all the drawing and a separate function that takes care of the logic(loop).

For now I added a redraw function that does the redrawing of all objects on screen.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('plot');
var context;

var keyX = 100;
var keyY = 100;

playerCar = new car(100, 100, 'red');
playerCar2 = new car(350, 100, 'blue');

init()

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  var keyPressed = event.keyCode;
  switch(keyPressed){
    case 104:
     playerCar.y += 1;
      break;
    case 98:
      playerCar.y -= 1;
      break;
    case 100:
      playerCar.x += 1;
      break;
    case 102:
      playerCar.x -= 1;
      break;
  }

  redraw()

  console.log('key Y = ' + playerCar.y);
  console.log('key X = ' + playerCar.x);
});

function init(){
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  redraw();
}
function redraw() {
  context.fillStyle = "green";
  var plot = {height: 800, width: 800};
  context.fillRect(1, 1, plot.width, plot.height);
  playerCar.draw();
  playerCar2.draw();
}

function car (keyX, keyY, color){
  carwidth = 150;
  carHeight = 100;
  this.x = keyX;
  this.y = keyY;
  this.color = color;
  this.draw = function (){
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, carwidth, carHeight);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <canvas id="plot" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: great thats what I wanted to know how to update the object settings, very new to object programming. Thank you also for the draw part I will look up what you said and work on this

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">


<output id="autox" >13</output>
<output id="autoy">180</output>


<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;
var autox;
function startGame() {

let autox = document.getElementById("autox").value;
let autox1 = (autox * 1);
var autoy = document.getElementById("autoy").value;
let autoy1 = (autoy * 1);

    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", autox1, autoy1);
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            return;
        } 
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 50;
        maxGap = 200;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += -1;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
<br>
<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
<p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
<p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
</body>
</html>
```